# Create video vom rendered OpenGL frames

Tags: opengl, video, ffmpeg, render, libavcodec

i am searching for a way to create a video from a row of frames i have rendered with OpenGL and transfered to ram as int array using the glGetTexImage function. is it possible to achieve this directly in ram (~10 secs video) or do i have to save each frame to the harddisk and encode the video afterwards?

i have found this sample http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html in an other SO question but is this still the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

today i got a hint to use this example http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=doc/examples/decoding_encoding.c;h=cb63294b142f007cf78436c5d81c08a49f3124be;hb=HEAD to see how h264 could be achieved. the problem when you want to encode frames rendered by opengl is that they are in RGB(A) and most codecs require YUV. for the convertion you can use swscale (ffmpeg) - an example how to use it can be found here http://web.me.com/dhoerl/Home/Tech_Blog/Entries/2009/1/22_Revised_avcodec_sample.c.html

as ananthonline stated the direct encoding of the frames is very cpu intensive but you can also write your frames with ffmpeg as rawvideo format, which supports the rgb24 pixelformat, and convert it offline with the cmd commands of ffmpeg.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross-platform way of doing it, you're probably going to have to use ffmpeg/libavcodec but on Windows, you can write an AVI quite simply using the resources [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1418/A-class-to-easily-generate-AVI-video-with-OpenGL-a).

Comment: the link sounds promissing but i forgot the request for h264 encoding so i think ffmpeg is the best way to achive this or ?

Comment: I don't believe you can directly do h.264 unless you're using DirectShow/Media Foundation - so your alternatives are to render as AVI and then perform an offline convert by invoking a command-line tool or to capture directly to H.264 by interfacing with the libavcodec. Remember that encoding to H.264 is CPU-intensive and might cause "glitches" in rendering unless you have a beefy CPU and/or light rendering code.